# Run Cordova app in IOS 11 sim

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ios11

How can I force the simulator to run IOS 11?
The following command doesn’t show IOS 11.

```
ionic Cordova emulate ios --list
```

Normally I use this command:

```
ionic Cordova emulate IOS --target=“iPad-Air” -l -c
```

I have ios 11 installed and the sim is running from inside XCode beta.

Thanks

Comment: I have sam problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328873/error-run-on-ios-emulator-after-update-to-ios-11-ionic-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need run command `cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest`
Detailed in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328873/error-run-on-ios-emulator-after-update-to-ios-11-ionic-3)